# Как отключить индексирование сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, seo, индексация, robots.txt

В Гугле и в Яндексе у меня индексируется сайт. Я захотел отключить индексирование сайта, в robots.txt сделал такую запись

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Достаточно ли этого, чтобы он не отображался в поисках Яндекса/Гугла или нужно еще удалять все из Яндекс веб-мастер и у Гугла?

В Wordpress так же включил «Запретить индексировать сайт в поисковиках»

Comment: Недостаточно, нужен ещё http-заголовок X-Robots-Tag

Comment: А для чего оно?

Comment: X-Robots-Tag: noindex - в robots.txt? Нужно ли удалять все из yandex webmaster/Гугл?

Comment: Нет, в http-заголовок

Comment: Так это meta tag robots. Я же написал, что я в WordPress поставил галочку

Comment: Если Wordpress только добавляет meta tag для html-страниц, то значит в не-html файлах его не будет и использовать http-заголовок всё равно надёжнее